# Push notification is not working for iphone

Tags: iphone

Push notification for iphone is not working on GoDaddy server for development provisioning profile.

Comment: Submit a trouble ticket and hope Danica Patrick gets right on it?

Answer (score 0):

Copy the HTTP and Net folder on server from your php directory and try again.

I also faced the same problem, but after copying these folder on server it works fine. Otherwise request your Go Daddy server to install these files on your web space.